# Multimeter not picking up a resistance

Tags: dc, resistance

I am making a set of speakers using 34.5 AWG magnet wire, and neodymium magnets to make a voice coil.

For my wire gauge and required length I should have ~3 Ω (DC), 4 Ω (AC).

The issue is when I went to check the resistance in the wire after I cut it from the spool, my multimeter didn't pick up any readings. I went and bought some alligator clip test leads and tried again; still nothing. I've used the multimeter before, the cables are plugged into the right ports, and I’ve tried all the range settings for DC resistance.

I'm trying to avoid winding the coil and gluing the whole unit together, just to find that it doesn't work.

Any suggestions to get the multimeter to read the resistance? It should be about 3 Ω for the length I cut.

Cheers

Comment: What multimeter are you using and what range are you using? You need to provide more information if you expect a useful answer.

Comment: Hey there. Barry - It's a Klein tools mm300, like I said I tried all range settings. It should be reasung on the lowest setting, 200. KingDuken - it's reading 0

Comment: Check the fuse?

Comment: Melt the magnet wire enamel insulation at the ends?

Comment: Try measuring the voltage across a battery to test the leads. Also make sure your battery is not low.

Comment: Blair - tested a 1.5 volt battery, it read fine. Sunnyskyguy - melted the wire ends, thought it would work but still no resistance reading. Just 0L

Comment: Solder the fine wires onto larger wires so you can make a good connection to each. You may just be having a hard time getting solid connections to both simultaneously.  Should that fail, AWG34 is reasonably robust by my standards but I suppose you could have broken it somewhere in the coiling process. But I'm betting on the connections being troublesome.

Comment: be sure that you have really melted or scrape off the enamel coating on ends of the magnet wire

Comment: Interesting... You have "OL" on your multimeter? OL stands for "open loop" indicating an open circuit, no continuity. OL is different than 0 (zero).

Answer (score 1):

The enamel-insulated magnet wire would require its ends to be scraped and tinned before soldering.

Answer (score 0):

To easily test that the meter is working correctly:

1. Select the 200 Ohm setting, it is at the very bottom of the meter dial
2. Connect the black lead to the Black jack and the red lead to the Red jack  on the right side of the meter
3. Touch the two leads (red and black) together and watch the readout. It should indicate 0.01 or perhaps 1.02 or at least some reading.

If the meter does not give you a value when you have performed these steps, then it is very likely that its fuse (inside the meter) has been blown. (mentioned above)
or the meter is not working in the Ohm setting anyway.

I have gone over these steps because you mention you expect a readings in DC and AC.

You will not get a DC or AC reading when using the meter on a piece of wire. You will get a reading on a piece of wire using the Ohm setting (providing the fuse is OK).

Comment: I'm only looking to read dc resistance, I just know that 3 dc is around 4 ac. I just did your test with both leads and it gave a reading of around 1.01 like you said. Just can't figure out why it won't give me a reading from the magnet wire. I melted the ends, and it's set to the lowest setting, 200 ohm